# How do you apply bilinear mapping to attribute based encryption?

Tags: abe

I'm new to both bilinear mapping and ABE. I have a vague idea of how bilinear mapping works now, but I don't understand how it applies to ABE. Can someone give me an example?

Comment: Could you be more precise in your question? What do you read about ABE and bilinear mapping? What do you understand about? What do you not understand about?

Answer (score 1):

You can study pages and papers below to understand bilinear maps (or pairing) and ABE.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing-based_cryptography

https://eprint.iacr.org/2004/086.pdf

https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/309.pdf

Comment: The linked page and papers are relevant, but we prefer self-contained answers, and here one seems possible (if not at all simple).

Comment: @mehdi mahdavi oliaiy  It looks like a beneficial contribution, but you have not yet answered the question.